# How to avoid recalculation of coordinates in graphviz every time I make a small changes?

Tags: svg, coordinates, graphviz, dot

I have a dot file with 1000 nodes and 1500 edges. It takes roughly 4 minutes for the dot command to run to generate the svg file.

Now, I am trying to make small changes like coloring some nodes/edges to make them more conspicuous. Do I have to wait for the 4 minutes every time I make small changes? Is there a way to avoid the recalculation of coordinates and reuse the previous calculations?

Answer (score 3):

One way to save some time is:

1. Calculate coordinates and output to dot format:

   ```
   dot original.dot -o intermediary.dot
   ```

   The output file is a text file with node and edge positions.
2. Modify your intermediary output file (add colors etc.)
3. Create the svg file based on your intermediary file, this time without calculating node/edge positions:

   ```
   neato -n2 -Tsvg intermediary.dot -o final.svg
   ```

Of course, your original file will not have all the changes you made to the intermediary dot file (you may want to add them back).

Answer (score 2):

svg files are xml files. So, if you can write xsl templates, you could apply an xslt transformation to it.

Here is an xsl template that might give you some ideas:
http://www.hokstad.com/making-graphviz-output-pretty-with-xsl